# Index/Match - in table containing multiple similar values

Tags: microsoft-excel

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**Purpose**:

Use a known "length" value to find correct column header, then search for a value in the column, then return index on the right hand of that data table.

**Background**:

1. Some values in table body are repeated in different columns
2. The values in the table body represent lower limits of intervals
3. The column headers in C4 to F4 represent lower limits of intervals
4. The row  headers in B5 to B8 each represent a unique index

TABLE:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K               
3           Length                      Header                  
4       **4.1   5   5.3 6**     Length: 5.4 5.3 =HLOOKUP($J$4;C4:F4;1)          
5   **7**   18  20  21  23      Strength    28              
9   **20**  22  23  25      Index   11  =INDEX(B5:B8;MATCH(J5;E5:E8;4))                 
7   **11**  24  25  27  28                                  
8   **16**  27  28  30  31
```

**Already achieved**:

1. The information in J4 & J5 is always given (i.e. known)
2. HLOOPKUP (J4) is used to identify the correct column header - and the correct result appears in K4, i.e. column E
3. The (INDEX/MATCH) formula in J6 then correctly searches the values under the column  E header (E5:E8 - which I have to type in) -
   and correctly identifies that "28" (J5) falls in the "27, " interval (E7) - and then correctly identifies the corresponding row header as "11" (B7)

**Assistance required**:

1. Currently I first have to run the HLOOKUP formula to determine the column header
2. Next I have to manually type in the column values (excluding the column header)  - based on the result of K4, into the formula in J6 in order to run the INDEX/MATCH function
3. So, I need assistance to automatically insert the column values (excluding the column header) based on the HLOOKUP result  into the INDEX/MATCH formula.
4. I would prefer using functions rather than VBA if at all possible

   [Screenshot of errors][1]The screenshot shows how some calculations give a #N/A result.

Regards. Rudi

Comment: I think instead of the Hlookup use an index match, which would give you the column index and not the column "label". You should be able to use a formula to convert that to the column index in your next index function.

Comment: Why you have `4` in your `INDEX(B5:B8, MATCH(J5, E5:E8, 4))` ? The third parameter of `MATCH` only ranges from `-1, 0, 1` for `greater than, exact match, less than`, not the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OFFSET` to shift the range from the upper leftmost cell to get the correct range.

```
=INDEX($B$5:$B$8, MATCH($J$5, OFFSET($C$5, 0, MATCH($J$4, $C$4:$F$4, 1)-1, ROWS($B$5:$B$8), 1), 1))
```

### Explanation

This behaves just like your `INDEX MATCH` formula, however I changed the `E5:E8` in your example to a relative range, defined by `OFFSET( ... )`

```
OFFSET($C$5, //Reference point
       0,    //Rows shifted below, in this case it doesn't shift the row
       MATCH($J$4, $C$4:$F$4, 1)-1, //Column shifted to the right, in this case it shifts from `1-4` minus 1.
       ROWS($B$5:$B$8),           //Height, in this case you want as many rows as the table has, taken from the left "header"
       1)    //Width, in this case you only want one column
```

---

`$C$5` is the upper leftmost cell on your values that is used as a reference point.

`MATCH($J$4, $C$4:$F$4, 1)-1` is to get the index of the column header. This is similar to your `HLOOKUP` formula, but instead it returns the column number (3rd column returns 2, for example)

`ROWS($B$5:$B$8)` is to get how many rows the table has, taken from how many rows the left "header" has

Comment: Thanks for speedy response Vylix. I have inserted your suggestions and table already shows a vast improvement. However, there are still some challenges (see table)                                                                                                                       : Length: 4.1  5 5.5  6
            Strength 18  21 26  31
              Result #N/A 7 #N/A #N/A
      Expected result 7  7 9  16                          Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot in the question?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance - but how do I do that? (read help re. Comments but did not find an answer)

Comment: I know how to make a screenshot but not how to attach to comment.

Comment: @RBurger edit your question, and add with the uploaded screenshot. Just provide the link, we can make it shown in the question.

Comment: I have already uploaded screenshot but have not yet seen any response.

Comment: In any case the problem lies with the data which is looked up in the table - it is not always numbers in sequence (1,2,3) but some numbers also represent lower limits of ranges (e.g. 1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 13, 17, 18...). This seems to confuse the formula provided.

Comment: After a careful evaluation of the formula, I made a mistake with the `MATCH` within the `OFFSET`. Add `-1` to it and it will work. And also update to your screenshot, change the last `0` to `1`.

Comment: Looks like you have nailed it this time Vylix! Thanks so much for your assistance.